# livecd remastering: which distro should i choose

Tags: linux, livecd

...I just want to add and configure some software. Just simple remaster. Like 2-5 new programs added. Could someone recommend me livecd i should base my remaster on, taking into account these requirements:

- KDE
- ability to install nvidia driver (it don't have to be added to remaster itself, i just want to be able to compile graphics drivers if they aren't on cd while running cd - that means distro should have binutils by default, etc)
- **i want to create my remaster while my computer is running from livecd** with all dependencies preinstalled on that livecd (so no need to configure my installed os to be able to do remaster)

?

---

Packages i plan to install rather aren't in any official repositories so i need to be able to install my own debs/rpms/source. 'Click and choose programs from dropdown list' rather  won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Knoppix 5.1.1 is what you would like?

See [Kyle Rankin at Google Techtalks "Remastering Knoppix without remastering"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdahQulIcUU)
If you're ok with that, you can just dump a bunch of stuff in your storage device and if you run knoppix next time, just tell it to resume session from that device.

Use Knoppix 5.1.1 CD edition or 5.3.1 DVD edition. I'm not sure you would want Knoppix 6 because it does not use KDE anymore

**No iso, no burning, nothing**

Same with **Puppy Linux**.

But this migth not be what you want - drivers etc, I'm not sure.
Maybe you can write scripts for copy-paste-run so-and-so?

I'm not sure really, but people love Knoppix and Puppy for these **session saving** features

*If it's urgent get hold of a local Linux guru.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SuSE Studio](http://susestudio.com/) to build a customized LiveCD based on the packages you require.
Another good option is [Ubuntu Customization Kit.](http://uck.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: someone before suggested suse studio and deleted his answer... suse studio is easy and all but it's too limited for me, it doesn't have packages i want on my cd. UCK can be used from livecd? I don't have local ubuntu install (and i don't really plan to install it, heh)

Comment: uck needs at least 5gb in /home to work so thats prolly not gonna work

Answer (score 0):

[Reconstructor](http://www.reconstructor.org) might work for what you need.

Comment: uhhh, i see deb there but no base iso... i want to remaster while my computer is running on some livecd. i don't want to change/install anything on my 'real' os. don't get me wrong - it's interesting soft. i like the idea. but i won't mess up with my real system only for one/few days project.

Comment: @Stan_: you should be able to install a deb onto a running livecd OS; it just gets "installed" to tmpfs (RAM drive) -- so you'll have to install it again after each reboot.  obviously you'll need *some* hard-drive partition to store your working copies of stuff, but you don't *need* a drive install.

Answer (score 0):

Archlinux is a pretty great distro all-around.  It's what I use http://www.archlinux.org/download/